# Qt doesn't find windows.h

Tags: windows, qt, qt5, visual-studio-2010

I'm running a simple program with Qt5, QtCreator under windows 7+msvc2010 with SDK7 installed. I have to call specific Windows functions in this program.

If I try to compile it, I always get:

> error: C1083: Cannot open include file: 'Windows.h': No such file or directory.

Of course, I set "normally" the dev. kit in QtCreator (Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler 10.0), and I try to run vcvars32.bat before. It still is not working.

Another point: Why when while compiling, do I not see any include (-I...) related to the Windows SDK?

Where is my mistake?

Comment: There shouldn't be any `-I` related to the Windows SDK; the compiler (environment) will know about them automatically.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `windows.h` instead of `Windows.h`? Just guessing (I don't use the Win API)